# each_value on nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got below nested object that is being put through `each_value`

```
{"B"=>#<Destination:0x2998b60 @city=#<City:0x2998bc0 @name="B", @destinations=
    {"C"=>#<Destination:0x2998a28 @city=#<City:0x2998aa0 @name="C", @destinations=
        {"A"=>#<Destination:0x2998920 @city=#<City:0x2998c20 @name="A", @destinations={...}>, @distance=3>}
    >, @distance=2>}
>, @distance=1>}
```

In below loop

```
@destinations.each_value do |dest|
    puts dest.city
    dest.city.all_routes_to(end_of_route, maximum_stops, stops + 1).each do |connection|
        connected_routes << build_route_to(dest).connect(connection)
    end
end
```

What I don't get is when I run this, I get B,C,A

So I presume that `each_value` does loop through all of its child objects aswell but couldn't find this in the Ruby documentation.

Is this how this function works or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The standard `each_value` method calls the block once for each key in the hash, passing it the value, per http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/each_value.  I can only assume that `@destinations` is getting modified by the code within the block or something else is generating output.